# Why a global variable (char[]) read in one function shows garbage when used in other function?

Tags: c++, global, turbo-c++

When i entered the value of id in read function it reads the correct value but when i print it in the display function it adds some garbage after it ... i tried adding '\0' after the string no change !
Please help me resolve the issue .
ALSO THIS IS ONLY HAPPENING IN TURBO C++ WHILE MY CODE RAN PERFECTLY IN DEV C++ AS WELL AS WHEN RUN WITH MINGW ON CMD.Please explain the reason for such absurd output in turbo c++.
here is my c++ code which i ran in turbo c++:

```
  #include <iostream.h>
    #include <string.h>
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <conio.h>
   //using namespace std;
   class Student
   {
    private:
        char name[50],course[10],id[10];
        long int roll_no,year;
public:
    void read()
    {
        //clrscr();
        cout<<"ENTER NAME"<<endl;
        gets(name);
        cout<<"ENTER ID"<<endl;
        cin>>id;
        cout<<"ENTER ROLL NUMBER"<<endl;
        cin>>roll_no;
        cout<<"ENTER COURSE"<<endl;
        cin.ignore();
        gets(course);
        cout<<"ENTER YEAR (in number)"<<endl;
        cin>>year;
    }
    void display()
    {
        cout<<"NAME:"<<name<<endl;
        cout<<"ID:"<<id<<" "<<endl;
        cout<<"ROLL NO:"<<roll_no<<endl;
        cout<<"COURSE AND YEAR:"<<course<<" "<<year<<"year"<<endl;
    }
};
int main()
{
    Student s;
    s.read();
    s.display();
    return 0;
}
```

now in output id is being added up with some random garbage value.

[image: OUTPUT SCREEN in turbo c++]

Comment: fyi, turbo c++ != c++.

Comment: That's because you use character buffers of fixed size `char *` instead of more convenient `std::string`, when you read into `name` you indeed read up to `\0` character, but you don't copy `\0` to the buffer `name`, so after your last meaningful character you're left with some garbage. The reason it worked in other compilers, because they by default fill the whole buffer of `name` with `\0` so the fact that you don't copy `\0` in the end yourself doesn't matter

Comment: @AlexeyLarionov Note that `std::string` won't work with a turbo c++ compiler.

Comment: You're mixing `std::string`s with C character arrays, this occasionally works, but only by mistake.  Pick one and stick with it and you'll be OK.

Comment: @AlexeyLarionov String as a data type don't work in TURBO C++, also variable "name" worked perfectly but "id " got added up with garbage .

Answer (score 0):

When we declare a char[] in turbo of size suppose 'n' and provide n characters to it does not have space for null character because turbo c++ need extra space for '\0' and so without an ending the string has garbage added to it. So if id[11] or >11 is declared then it will have space for '\0' and so no garbage will be printed.